# Eclipse memory renderer - image

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Is there a plugin for viewing in-memory images at eclipse?

something like the HEX\unsigned\signed integer rendering, only that I want to show pixel greyscale values...

[image: Like this, only for images]

if there isn't - I would like to start developing one, is there a plugin framework for those renderers?

Thanks